# How to decrease the autocompletion delay in visual studio code for python imported packages?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, opencv

I am using python 3.7.3 and visual studio code 1.33.1. When I import any library like cv2 or numpy and try to use it, the autocompletion takes 4-5 seconds to identify the functions. When I use the default functions like print(),slice(), etc., they autocomplete within 1 second.

I tried using the following config

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--extension-pkg-whitelist=cv2"],
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "C:\Users\Pratik\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\cv2"
]
```

```
import cv2
import numpy
cv2.   #here I need to list all functions
```

I expect to decrease the autocompletion delay from 4-5 seconds to 1s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to `python.autoComplete.extraPaths`, try setting the [`jediEnabled`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_intellisense-engine-settings) setting to false, to enable the [Microsoft Python Language Server](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/introducing-the-python-language-server/) (which is disabled by default):

```
"python.jediEnabled": false
```

Then restart/reload VS Code.

When the window is reloaded, open the Output tab then click on your Python file.  You should see a "*Starting Microsoft Python language server.*" message displayed (select *Python* from the top-right dropdown to see it). There should also be an "*Analyzing in background...*" message at the bottom status bar.

[image: output tab]

Wait for the "*Analyzing..*" message to disappear (meaning it's finished). If you're enabling this for the first time, it takes a while to download. Also, check the output logs that the language server is searching the correct *site-packages* paths (paths added to `python.autoComplete.extraPaths` should appear in the "*Configuration Search Paths*").

The autocomplete/intellisense should be much faster now.

[image: gif]

Related:

- [What is the difference between jedi and python language server in VS code IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55897160/2745495)

Comment: This still takes about 2 seconds before it shows up. Is that to be expected?

Comment: @Mythaar Hmm I don't know, sorry, it appears quite instantaneous to me on my current env (it actually appears faster than the GIF I posted in this answer). You could try tweaking the [Intellisense settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_customizing-intellisense), especially the `quickSuggestionsDelay`. It's also possible that it's caused by some other extension, so try disabling all extensions except for Python, then re-enable one-by-one. Other than that, I think you'll need to post a new question or raise an issue over at VS Code.

Comment: I think it may just be something to do with the `cv2` library. I tried installing tensorflow and calling autocompletions, and that only took half a second.